# Preparing .app for iTunes

Tags: iphone, xcode, deployment

I know this is a basic question, but the Apple Developer Guide just refers to it as "your binary."

I have built it in Xcode 4.2 and it runs fine on my device, I'm ready to upload it to iTunes but I can't figure out how to create my binary. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

"your binary" is referring to your App file in iTunes Connect *after* you have uploaded it.  To create this binary, all you need to do is upload a release build of your App to iTunes Connect, and then your "binary" will exists.

Comment: Your app status needs to be "Waiting For Upload"

Answer (score 0):

After you built your app for a release right-mouse-click on the `product name` then choose `Show in Finder` now zip does two files there and this is your binary that you will have to upload.